# convert SMILES column to ROMol column with in the same pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, rdkit

How can I convert SMILES column to new SDF(ROMol) column in the same pandas data frame using RDkit or other?

for example:

```
ID SMILES
1  Oc1ccc2c(noc2c1)c3cccc4ccc(O)cc34
2  Oc1cc(C=C)c2cc(ccc2c1)c3ccc(O)c(F)c3
3  CC1=C(C(=O)c2ccc(O)cc12)c3ccc(O)cc3
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`rdkit.Chem` has a module called `PandasTools` which can be used to create dataframes prepopulated with the columns you require.
http://www.blopig.com/blog/2017/02/using-rdkit-to-load-ligand-sdfs-into-pandas-dataframes/

If you wish to just edit an existing dataframe, the function you need is `AddMoleculeColumnToFrame` in `rdkit.Chem.PandasTools` http://www.rdkit.org/Python_Docs/rdkit.Chem.PandasTools-module.html